# Как пропустить итерацию в цикле for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, циклы, for

Пробовал пропустить итерацию с помощью оператора `continue`. Но, видимо, он не подходит. Задача описана ниже в комментарии к коду:

```
# Задача программы:
# - переводить любой текст в следующий формат: "сЛуЧаЙнЫй ТеКсТ"
# - т.е., каждая новая буква в слове должна отличаться в регистре от предыдущей
# - пробелы пропускаются

user_text = "любой случайно набранный текст"
```

Сначала я хотел написать что-то типа:

```
for i in user_text:
    i = i.upper() # метод upper() выносит слова в верхний регистр
    continue
```

Но потом понял, что это не верно.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Comment: я наверное что-то не понимаю, но почему такие легкие учебные задания набирают столько голосов...

Comment: Конкретно эта задача оказалась неожиданно сложной в реализации, а её кажущаяся простота привлекла много отвечающих. Активность отвечающих удерживала её в топе задач. Кто в топе, тот получает много голосов. И отвечающие тоже голосуют за. Как-то так.

Answer (score 13):

Пропускать итерации не нужно. В задании сказано "переводить любой текст". В том числе и такой "ПРИВЕТ" -> "пРиВеТ". Следовательно, иногда вам нужно поднимать регистр, иногда опускать. Иногда символ не должен меняться (например пробел), но и в этом случае пропускать итерацию нельзя - нужно проверить что это пробел и ничего не делать.

Если всё это учесть, то получится такой (нерабочий) код:

```
for i in user_text:
    if not i.isalpha():
        continue
    # хитрое условие
    if ...:
        i = i.lower()
    else:
        i = i.upper()
```

Этот код работает, но ничего не делает. Строки в Питоне неизменны: сама идея, что можно отредактировать отдельные символы и вписать обратно в строку, не верна. Нужно изготавливать копию строки.

Работающий код ниже. Во-первых, регистр переключается без булевых флагов и деления с остатком. Во-вторых, это генератор. В-третьих, мои любимые скобки подряд `next(cases)(c)`. В-четвёртых, обращение к методу класса без упоминания экземпляра (в Питоне пишут `'s'.upper()`, но можно и `str.upper('s')`):

```
import itertools


def mixed_case(s):
    cases = itertools.cycle((str.lower, str.upper))
    for c in s:
        if c.isalpha():
            yield next(cases)(c)
        else:
            yield c


for s in (
    'любой случайно набранный текст',
    'любой, дАжЕ "СЛУЧАЙНО" набраный ТЕКСТ',
    'Специальный выпуск сериала Друзья телеканала HBO Max получил официальную дату премьеры в России'
):
    print(''.join(mixed_case(s)))
```

> ```
> $ python mixed_case.py 
> лЮбОй СлУчАйНо НаБрАнНыЙ тЕкСт
> лЮбОй, ДаЖе "СлУчАйНо" НаБрАнЫй ТеКсТ
> сПеЦиАлЬнЫй ВыПуСк СеРиАлА дРуЗьЯ тЕлЕкАнАлА hBo MaX пОлУчИл ОфИцИаЛьНуЮ дАтУ пРеМьЕрЫ в РоСсИи
> ```

Код можно переписать компактно если воспользоваться выражением-генератором и тернарным `if`:

```
def mixed_case(s):
    cases = itertools.cycle((str.lower, str.upper))
    return (next(cases)(c) if c.isalpha() else c for c in s)
```

Пользователь [TigerTV.ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/281034/tigertv-ru) предложил ипользовать `map`:

```
def mixed_case(s):
    cases = itertools.cycle((str.lower, str.upper))
    return map(lambda c: next(cases)(c) if c.isalpha() else c, s)
```

Comment: хороший трюк с циклами!

Comment: Вот это красивый код

Comment: "и меня с собой возьмите"... тут, скорее, все - за вами )) yield - прекрасен

Comment: можно завернуть в `map` и получить 2 строки: `return map(lambda x: next(cases)(x) if x.isalpha() else x, s)`

Comment: Вы правы, сделаю позже. Только я предпочитаю в данном случае выражение-генератор. И надо ответить на вопрос ТС. :)

Answer (score 10):

Можно так:

```
user_text = 'любой, дАжЕ "СЛУЧАЙНО" набраный ТЕКСТ'

i = 0
simbols_list = []

for s in user_text.lower():
    if s.isalpha():
        simbols_list.append(s if not i%2 else s.upper())
        i += 1
    else:
        simbols_list.append(s)

new_text = ''.join(simbols_list)
```

в `new_text` будет:

```
лЮбОй, ДаЖе "СлУчАйНо" НаБрАнЫй ТеКсТ
```

---

Выполняется требование "каждая новая буква в слове должна отличаться в регистре от предыдущей", пропускает не только пробелы, но и знаки препинания (любую "небукву"). Спасибо [Vadim.Sharoikin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286774/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-for/1286782#comment2269304_1286782) за уточнение!

Comment: моно еще `if s.isalpha()` , мало ли запятые или другие знаки будут

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin не только "моно", но и "нуно" ;) спасибо, дополнил

Answer (score 7):

В Python строки - неизменяемый тип данных, поэтому изменить посимвольно не получится. Можно сделать через новую строку:

```
# Задача программы:
# - переводить любой текст в следующий формат: "сЛуЧаЙнЫй ТеКсТ"
# - т.е., каждая новая буква в слове должна отличаться в регистре от предыдущей
# - пробелы пропускаются
user_text = "любой случайно набранный текст"
new_user_text, i = '', 0                                # итоговая строка; счетчик символов в строке, кроме пробелов
for c in user_text.lower():                             # сразу привели все символы к нижнему регистру
    new_user_text += c.upper() if i%2 else c            # каждый второй символ приводим к верхнему регистру
    i += 1 if c.isalpha() else 0                        # увеличиваем счетчик символов в строке если это буква
print(new_user_text)
```

Comment: можно просто `c.isalpha()` прибавлять

Answer (score 6):

Можно и с `continue`, главное знать где применить:

```py
text = 'Специальный выпуск сериала "Друзья" телеканала HBO Max получил официальную дату премьеры в России'

switch = False
res = []
for t in text:
    if not t.isalpha():
        res.append(t)   
        continue
    if switch:
        res.append(t.upper())
    else:
        res.append(t.lower())
    switch = not switch
res = "".join(res)

print(text)
print(res)

# Специальный выпуск сериала "Друзья" телеканала HBO Max получил официальную дату премьеры в России
# сПеЦиАлЬнЫй ВыПуСк СеРиАлА "дРуЗьЯ" тЕлЕкАнАлА hBo MaX пОлУчИл ОфИцИаЛьНуЮ дАтУ пРеМьЕрЫ в РоСсИи
```

Answer (score 3):

```
user_text = "любой случайно набраный текст"
user_text2 = ""
for i, s in enumerate(user_text):
    if s != " ":
        user_text2 += s.upper() if i % 2 == 0 else s.lower()
    else:
        user_text2 += " "
print(user_text2)
# ЛюБоЙ СлУчАйНо нАбРаНыЙ ТеКсТ
```

Более короткая запись

```
user_text = "любой случайно набраный текст"
print("".join([s.upper() if s != " " and i % 2 == 0 else s.lower() for i, s in enumerate(user_text)]))
# ЛюБоЙ СлУчАйНо нАбРаНыЙ ТеКсТ
```

Comment: в задаче # Пробелы пропускаются

Comment: @Jack_oS внёс правки

Comment: не помогло. У вас по обе стороны пробелов одинаковый регистр, а должен быть разный