# Вывод текста "заборчиком"

Tags: python, строки

Необходимо вывести строку формата *слово*другоеслово* заборчком, т.е. каждая последующая буква в другом регистре (*СлОвО*дРуГоЕсЛоВо*).
Имеется такой код:

```
text = input("Введите строку: ")
for i in range(len(text)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(text[i].upper(), end="")
    else:
        print(text[i], end="")
```

Проблема заключается в том, что после символа '*' буква не меняяет своей регистр и получается так:

```
*СлОвО*ДрУгОеСлОвО*
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как пропустить итерацию в цикле for?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286774/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-for)

Comment: ```python
if text[i] == ' ': continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string
text_sample = '*слово*другоеслово*'
i = 0
for simvol in text_sample:
    if simvol in string.punctuation:
        print(simvol, end='')
        continue
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(simvol.upper(), end='')
    else:
        print(simvol.lower(), end='')
    i += 1
```

Comment: simvol... character

Comment: @wanna_feel, ну да простят меня англоговорящие =)) я немецкий изучал =)

Answer (score 0):

Самая банальная версия

```
text = "*моя*строка*"
t = "l"
for i in range(len(text)):
    if text[i] == "*":
        print(text[i], end="")
    else:
        if t == "l":
            print(text[i].upper(), end="")
            t = "u"
        else:
            print(text[i].lower(), end="")
            t = "l"
```

Используем переменную t для определения регистра предыдущей буквы (u - upper, l - lower), т.е. после каждого изменения меняем её.
От изменения регистра символа * изабвляемся первым if.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]