# Как проще всего преобразовать строку в CaMeLcAsE?

Tags: python, строки

На вход подается строка, на выходе должно быть та же строка, но в cAmElCaSe.

Пример:

```
    ввод: Someword

    вывод: sOmEwOrD
```

Я бы делал так

```
string = "Someword"
l=[]
count=0
for i in string:
    count+=1
    if count%2==0:
        l.append(i.upper())
    else:
        l.append(i)
print("".join(l))
```

Есть ли вариант проще?

Comment: Так должно получиться `w w w w w` -> `W W W W W` ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как пропустить итерацию в цикле for?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286774/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-for)

Answer (score 2):

Подскажу вариант с регулярными выражениями:

```
x = 'qwerty'
re.sub(r'(\b|\w)(\w)', lambda x: x.group(1).lower()+x.group(2).upper(), x)
```

> 'QwErTy'

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так:

```
my_str = 'Someword'

print(''.join(ele.lower() if index % 2 == 0 else ele.upper() for index, ele in enumerate(my_str)))
```

Вывод

```
sOmEwOrD
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest as zip_l

s = "ЯблокОs"
res = ''.join(map(''.join, zip_l(s[::2].upper(), s[1::2].lower(), fillvalue='')))
print(res) # ЯбЛоКоS
```

Либо через итераторы:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest as zip_l

s = "ЯблокOs"
it = iter(s)
pairs = zip_l(map(str.upper, it), map(str.lower, it), fillvalue='')
res = ''.join(map(''.join, pairs))
print(res) # ЯбЛоКоS
```

Ну и теперь добавляем новое требование. Теперь преобразуется не только слово, но и строка:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest as zip_l

def upperlower(word):
    it = iter(word)
    pairs = zip_l(map(str.upper, it), map(str.lower, it), fillvalue='')
    return ''.join(map(''.join, pairs))

def uplow_str(s):
    return ' '.join(map(upperlower, s.split()))

s = "I like The ЯблокOs and i     don't    like           Spaces"
res = uplow_str(s)
print(res) # I LiKe ThE ЯбЛоКoS AnD I DoN'T LiKe SpAcEs
```

Comment: Группы пробелов заменяются одним пробелом.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да, все верно и первая буква каждого слова заглавная.